# batch script how i use a variable for return a another variable with the same name

Tags: batch-file

hi how i use a variable for return a another variable with the same name??????

%%b = file3

i want %%b return %file3%
like %%%b%

i need to use value in %file3% etc... when the loop job on file3 . zip

```
set file3=Bin64\Setup.exe -Install -output screen
set file8=Setup.exe -Install
set file11=someanotherdir\Setup.exe -options
set stuff= file.zip file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip file4.zip file5.zip file6.zip file7.zip file8.zip file9.zip file10.zip file11.zip
set count=1
:while
For /f "tokens=%count%" %%a in ("%stuff%") do (
echo %%a
set /a "count+=1"
echo File to work: %%a
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=. " %%b in ("%%a") do (

rem ###\/ HERE [%%%b%] ???? ###
if [%%%b%] EQU [] (

echo No option detected for: %%b
goto :while
)

rem ###\/ AND HERE %%%b% ###
echo Execute this cmd for this file: %%%b%

)
pause
goto :while
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "file3=Setup.exe -options"
Set "file8=Setup.exe -other"
Set "file11=Setup.exe -alternative"
Set "stuff=file.zip file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip file4.zip file5.zip file6.zip file7.zip file8.zip file9.zip file10.zip file11.zip"
For %%A In (%stuff%) Do If Defined %%~nA Echo([Extracting %%A]-[Running !%%~nA!]
Timeout -1
```